# Receiving email using Imap through SSL connection using javax.mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap

I want to receive emails using imap trough secure connection. I implemented it using using javax.mail api. But there are different server configurations. As I found

```
// 1)
store = session.getStore(imaps);
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", username, password);
```

Which make 'isSSL' true and use port 993 which is secure port to connect in javax.mail. Following configuration also prove secure connection through 993 port.

```
// 2)
properties.put("mail.imap.host", "imap.gmail.com");
properties.put("mail.imap.port", "993");
properties.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback","false");
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", 993);
```

These two methods work fine. Can you please tell me what is different between these two and what is the correct way to receive messages through secure connection.
Futher I found;
"mail.imap.ssl.enable" and "mail.imap.starttls.enable.
Can you tell me whether i needed these two also.

Comment: Everithing you need is here https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ

Comment: Yes, read the FAQ.  Please.  Especially the list of [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  And there's lots more information on the [JavaMail project page](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).  In particular, see the [SSLNOTES.txt](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/SSLNOTES.txt) file.

Answer (score 7):

> Setting various socketFactory properties. Long, long ago JavaMail didn't have built in support for SSL connections, so it was necessary to set these properties to use SSL. This hasn't been the case for years; remove these properties and simplify your code. The easiest way to enable SSL support in current versions of JavaMail is to set the property "mail.smtp.ssl.enable" to "true". (Replace "smtp" with "imap" or "pop3" as appropriate.)
>   https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes

```
String host = "mail.example.com";
String username = "email@example.com";
String password = "mysecretpassword";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");

Session session = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(props);
Store store = session.getStore("imap");
store.connect(host, username, password);

Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();


inbox.close(false);
store.close();
```

Comment: In addition to SSL enabled, I had to use google account 'app password' instead of standard password that is used to login to your gmail account & ensure that imap was enabled in the email account settings.